# Trying to calculate sum only when shown based on value in td marked with id with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got several fields in a table that show and hide using checkboxes. I want to calculate the sum in a total field at the bottom of the table with only values that have been switch up to visible. Right now I'm only able to get it to show all values in the total instead of just visible ones.

These scripts combine to operate all the functions on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(document).ready(function() { 
                $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() { 
                    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value"); 
                    $("." + inputValue).toggle(); 

                }); 
            }); 
</script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function()
    {
        var divId = $(this).attr("id");

        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("." + divId).show();
        }
        else {
            $("." + divId).hide();
        }

    });
});
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the basic structure of the tables without css.

```
<center>  
        <div style="width:600px;">  
                <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox"
                        value="lippro"> Lippro</label>
        </div>
</center>


<div class="lippro" style="float:left;width:45%;display:none;">
<p>
    <strong>Lippro</strong> <br />
    <input class="my-activity" type="checkbox" value="42"> example<br/>
    <input class="my-activity" type="checkbox" value="43"> example<br/>
    <input class="my-activity" type="checkbox" value="44"> example<br/>
    <input class="my-activity" type="checkbox" value="45"> example<br/>
    <input class="my-activity" type="checkbox" value="46"> example<br/>
</p>
</div>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Pro</th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th>Price</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="displaytable">
<tr class="41" style="display:none">
<td>example</td>
<td></td>
<td></td><td class="price">4500</td></tr><tr class="42" style="display:none">
<td>example</td>
<td></td>
<td></td><td class="price">7800</td></tr><tr class="43" style="display:none">
<td>First Area</td>
<td></td>
<td></td><td class="price">6900</td></tr><tr class="44" style="display:none">
<td>example</td>
<td></td>
<td></td><td class="price">6000</td></tr><tr class="45" style="display:none">
<td>example</td>
<td></td>
<td></td><td class="price">8500</td></tr><tr class="46" style="display:none">
<td>example</td>
<td></td>
<td></td><td class="price">8500</td></tr>
<tfoot class="shown"><tr><td colspan="3">Total:</td>
<td id="total"></td></tr></tfoot>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried to work with this javascript function but it counts all totals not just shown ones.

```
var cls = document.getElementById("displaytable").getElementsByTagName("td");
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++){
    if(cls[i].className == "countable"){
    sum += isNaN(cls[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(cls[i].innerHTML);
    }
}   
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML += sum;
```

That was taken from the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63gdq8pr/1/) found here.

Comment: Your JavaScript sums td elements with the class "countable" but I don't see where you add/remove that class. Seems like after `$("." + divId).show();` would be a good place to add the class, and after `$("." + divId).hide();` would be a good place to remove it.

Comment: Thanks @Michael . From what your saying do you think this is the direction I should go? Change the id="price" tag to class="price" and then have the javascript update class name on both add and remove?

Comment: Can you update your code to create a minimal reproducible example? Right now the HTML is invalid because you're using the ID "price" more than once, and you have an orphan </label> tag. I also don't see how you're calling the bit of code that calculates the sum. Not critical but you have duplicate script tags, and all code can go in one $(document).ready call.

Comment: Thanks for that I was typing it over and used Id instead of Class for the price in there. @Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're a newbie...

```js
const displayTable = document.getElementById('display-table')
  ,   lipProCkBxs  = document.querySelectorAll('#lip-pro input[type=checkbox]')
  ,   tableTotal   = document.querySelector('#display-table tfoot tr td:last-child')
  ;
function showTR()
  {
  let total = 0
    ;
  lipProCkBxs.forEach( CkBx=>
    {
    let TRlist = displayTable.querySelectorAll('.c'+CkBx.value)
    if (CkBx.checked) 
      {
      TRlist.forEach(TR=>
        {
        TR.style='display: table-row'
        total += Number( TR.cells[3].textContent )
        })
      }
    else
      { TRlist.forEach(TR=>TR.style='') }
    })
  tableTotal.textContent = total
  }


// first time
lipProCkBxs.forEach( CkBx=>
  {
  CkBx.checked  = false
  CkBx.onchange = showTR
  })
```

```css
body  { font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
Table { border-collapse: collapse; margin-top: 1em; width:20em; }
td    { border: 1px solid grey; padding: 2px 10px; }
thead { background-color: turquoise;}
tfoot { background-color: orchid;}

#display-table tbody tr { display: none; }

#display-table tbody tr td:last-child,
#display-table tfoot tr td:last-child { text-align: right;}
```

```html
<div id="lip-pro">
    <h3>Lippro</h3>
    <label> <input class="my-activity" type="checkbox" value="41" /> v41 </label>
    <label> <input class="my-activity" type="checkbox" value="42" /> v42 </label>
    <label> <input class="my-activity" type="checkbox" value="43" /> v43 </label>
    <label> <input class="my-activity" type="checkbox" value="44" /> v44 </label>
    <label> <input class="my-activity" type="checkbox" value="45" /> v45 </label>
    <label> <input class="my-activity" type="checkbox" value="46" /> v46 </label>
  </div>

  <table id="display-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Pro</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="c41" >
        <td>example v41</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="price">4500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="c42" >
        <td>example v42</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="price">7800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="c43" >
        <td>First Area v43</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="price">6900</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="c44" >
        <td>example v44</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="price">6000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="c45" >
        <td>example v45</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="price">8500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="c46" >
        <td>example v46</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="price">8500</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>Total:</td>
        <td colspan="3">0</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
```

Comment: Good answer, but an explanation on how the code works will definitely help more people who will see this answer in the future.

Comment: all answers  on this small sample code are on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ .. Stackoverflow is not a place to teach programming lessons

Comment: Ah, makes sense.